# Subdiretório do repositório aparece como um link vazio no GitHub

Tags: git, github

Estou com um problema ao adicionar um projeto no gitHub, não consigo acessar o diretório 'frontend', já tentei algumas soluções, mas sem resultado.

[image: Pasta 'frontend' com a seta]

[image: Erro no terminal]

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema é que existe um repositório git dentro do diretório `frontend`, que "conflita" com o repositório da pasta raiz do seu projeto. Dessa maneira, o repositório contido na pasta raiz irá ignorar o conteúdo do subdiretório, pois o "repositório responsável" pelo subdiretório é o que está contido no mesmo.

O GitHub, por sua vez, entende que quando isso acontece, a pasta do repositório raíz deve apresentada como um link para acessar o outro repositório, que seria um repositório do GitHub separado apenas para o diretório `frontend`. Porém, como você não está enviando o repositório do subdiretório para um repositório separado no GitHub, o mesmo acaba sendo apresentado como uma página vazia ou inacessível no website.

Se você utilizou geradores para criar o projeto da aplicação front-end do seu projeto, como o `create-react-app` ou semelhantes, pode ser que o gerador tenha criado, automáticamente, um repositório Git naquela pasta para você, o que estaria causando esse problema.

---

## O que fazer

1. Execute o comando `git rm --cached frontend`
2. Exclua a pasta `.git` contida dentro da pasta `frontend`. A pasta `.git`fica escondida, então você precisa fazer com que o explorador de arquivos exiba arquivos escondidos para poder visualizá-la e excluí-la visualmente. Ou então, você pode usar um comando de terminal para isso.

   Windows: `rmdir frontent/.git`

   macOS/Linux: `rm -rf frontend/.git`
3. Execute o comando `git add frontend`

Feito isso, você pode commitar e fazer um push novamente para o repositório remoto, e o subdiretório deverá ser trackeado corretamente pelo GitHub.

Pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008290/git-how-to-make-outer-repository-and-embedded-repository-work-as-common-standal

Comment: Muito obrigado! Anteriormente eu estava procurando a pasta .git pelo Visual Studio Code e não estava encontrando, ao abrir no próprio disco ela estava aparecendo, agora deu certo!